# PetaPOCO T4 Template, generate multiple files (one for each table)

Tags: t4, petapoco

I wanted to try PetaPOCO and I was reading a tutorial on how to use their T4 template, and from what I understood it will generate one file "Database.cs" which will include all classes/tables.

Is there a way to generate one file per class/table instead (ex: Employee.cs, Company.cs, Job.cs..etc?

Comment: You can. This is a nice feature to add, but it implies a big set of modification with the t4 template provided... plus you will have to deal with configuration and namespaces..... it makes me wonder if anyone already did this???? Like the nugget package using repository pattern and petapoco...

Comment: @Minus I never used T4 before so I'm not sure where to start. I tried searching but didn't find anything conclusive. To me it makes more sense to use one file per table as opposed to use one large file for the entire database, especially when multiple developers are involved. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You also can do what you want, without any T4 files. You just decorate your POCO with  Attributes (TableName, PrimaryKey, Column, ...). This is manual, but it works.

Comment: @Minus True, but that defeats the purpose since the point of using templates is to save time.